# Quick Sort. C++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Доброго времени суток.
Изучаю алгоритмы и в качестве задания реализовал быструю сортировку(см. код ниже).
Сравниваю с алгоритмами в мировой паутине, ничем кардинально не отличается, но мой вызывает Stack Overflow, подскажите, почему?

```
void my_qsort(vector<int>& arr, int l, int r)
{
    int left = l;
    int right = r;
    int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

    while (left <= right) {
        while (arr[left] < mid) {
            left++;
        }
        while (arr[right] > mid) {
            right--;
        }
        if (left <= right) {
            swap(arr[left++], arr[right++]);
        }
    }
    if (l < right) {
        my_qsort(arr, l, right);
    }
    if (r > left) {
        my_qsort(arr, r, left);
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, центральный элемент (mid) неправильный, он должен быть элементом из массива, то есть `mid = arr[eft + (right - left) / 2];` а проще `mid = arr[(left+right)/2];`

Comment: Да ваш код вообще делает черт знает что. Одно сравнение `arr[left] < mid` чего стоит - вот что оно делает, по-вашему?...

Comment: Во-вторых, второй рекурсивный вызов со странными границами. Должно быть `my_qsort(arr, left, r)`

Comment: @Harry сравнивает текущий элемент с опорным, если он меньше, переходит к следующему, верно?

Comment: @ТарасСус да, таким образом в конце каждого рекурсивного вызова элементы слева от "опорного" (мне кажется, что понятнее "центрального") не больше него, а справа не меньше.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, внёс Ваши поправки, всё равно переполнение стека.

Comment: @ТарасСус я их делал после беглого осмотра. Под отладкой где проблема возникает? Еще одну ошибку только что увидел: `swap(arr[left++],  arr[right--])`

Comment: @АлексейСаровский это и есть последняя ошибка, спасибо Вам большое, впредь, буду внимательней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void my_qsort(vector<int>& arr, int l, int r)
{
    int left = l;
    int right = r;
    int mid = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    while (left <= right) {
        while (arr[left] < mid) {
            left++;
        }
        while (arr[right] > mid) {
            right--;
        }
        if (left <= right) {
            swap(arr[left++], arr[right--]);
        }
    }
    if (l < right) {
        my_qsort(arr, l, right);
    }
    if (r > left) {
        my_qsort(arr, left, r);
    }
}
```